# How to render multiple slots in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I render the following template in Vue3 `setup()` function using the `h()` function?

```html
<label v-for="service in services" :key="service">
  <slot name="before" :service="service"></slot>
    foobar
  <slot name="after" :service="service"></slot>
</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`h()` arguments](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments) are:

```js
// @returns {VNode}
h(
  // {String | Object | Function } tag
  // An HTML tag name, a component or an async component.
  // Using function returning null would render a comment.
  //
  // Required.
  'div',

  // {Object} props
  // An object corresponding to the attributes, props and events
  // we would use in a template.
  //
  // Optional.
  {},

  // {String | Array | Object} children
  // Children VNodes, built using `h()`,
  // or using strings to get 'text VNodes' or
  // an object with slots.
  //
  // Optional.
  [
    'Some text comes first.',
    h('h1', 'A headline'),
    h(MyComponent, {
      someProp: 'foobar'
    })
  ]
)
```

The component's [`setup()` arguments](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments) are below. `setup()` can also [return a render function](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-render-functions) (a function that returns a `VNode` from `h()`):

```js
setup(
  // {Object} Component prop values
  props,

  // {Object} Contains `attrs`, `emit`, and `slots`
  context
)
```

The context's `slots` property contains functions for each given slot. These functions receive arguments that are passed to the slot as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props), and each function returns the corresponding slot's `VNode`. For example, to get the `before` slot's `VNode` and pass a slot prop of `service`, call `context.slots.before({ service: 'myService' })`.

So the equivalent render function of your template would look similar to the following:

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    services: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  setup({ services }, { slots }) {
    return () =>
      services.map((service) =>
        h(                             //
          'label',                     //
          {                            // <label :key="service">
            key: service,              //
          },                           //
          [
            slots.before({ service }), //   <slot name="before" :service="service" />
            'foobar',                  //   foobar
            slots.after({ service })   //   <slot name="after" :service="service" />
          ]
        )                              // </label>
      )
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setup-render-functions-in-vue-3-setuj?file=/src/components/Demo.vue:161-394)